# How to get variant by variant Id from product object using by graphql Shopify

Tags: graphql, shopify

Query so far 
`{
  product1: product(id: "gid://shopify/Product/777854222396") {
    title
    totalVariants
    variants(first:99) {
      .....
    }
    hasOutOfStockVariants
  }
  product2: product(id: "gid://shopify/Product/511571296316") {
    title
  }
}`

What can be done to fetch variant based on id

Answer (score 0):

I have found `ProductVariant` on their [GraphQL Admin API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/graphql-admin-api/reference/object/productvariant) reference docs, you can take reference from their else I didn't find any `ProductVariant` `Schema` open at `QueryRoot` as defined here in the open [graphQL admin panel](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/graphiql) although they have mentioned an [example](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/graphql-admin-api/getting-started#example-queries).

```
query {
  productVariant(id: "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/10782354800682") {
    inventoryItem {
      inventoryLevels (first:10) {
        edges {
          node {
            location {
              name
            }
            available
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```